# Word Count on Column in Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The official Spark documentation has the following example of a word count:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```

How do I do the same on words in a column?

Assume a dataframe as follows

```
val df = spark.sql("""select ' a b c' col
             union all
             select ' a b c' col"""
```

I can't get the following attempt to work

```
df.map(row => row.getAs[String](0).split(" ").map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#explode) (convert single column values into multiple rows) the contents of each row by specifying the delimiter (which just the space character   here, of course) the `split` is going to be based on.

And you also need to sure every row of the column is trimmed (by using the `trim` method) from spaces at the start and/or end of the `String`, because without trimming you are going to have wordcounts for spaces as well.

So you can use something like this:

```
val df = spark.sql("""select ' a b c' col union all select ' a b c' col""")
  .withColumn("words", explode(split(trim(col("col")), " ")))
  .groupBy("words")
  .count()
```

And the resulting `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|words|count|
+-----+-----+
|    c|    2|
|    b|    2|
|    a|    2|
+-----+-----+
```